# How to assign Float type field to a Char type field in odoo 15?

Tags: odoo-15

Full Code:

```
from odoo import fields, models, api

class ExtraWeight(models.Model):
    _name = 'courier.extra.weights'
    _description = 'Charge setting for Extra Weight'
    _rec_name = 'combination'

    extra_weight = fields.Float(string='Next (KG)', required=True, translate=True)
    extra_charge = fields.Float(string='Charge for next Weight (TK)', required=True, translate=True)
    max_weight = fields.Float(string='Max Wight (KG)', required=True, translate=True)
    combination = fields.Char('Combination', compute='_compute_fields_combination')

    @api.depends('extra_weight', 'extra_charge')
def _compute_fields_combination(self):
    for record in self:
        record.combination = 'Extra Increment:' + str(record.extra_weight) + '(KG)  Rate' + str(record.extra_charge) + '(TK) Max:'+str(record.max_weight)+'(KG)'
```

I want to set `'Extra Increment:' + str(record.extra_weight) + '(KG)  Rate' + str(record.extra_charge) + '(TK) Max:'+str(record.max_weight)+'(KG)'` to `combination`. But I am getting the following error:

```
COALESCE types text and double precision cannot be matched
LINE 1: ...CE("courier_extra_weights__extra_weight"."value", "courier_e..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. It seems `Char` is not suitable as per your output length. Replace field type from `Char` to `Text`